# Is there any way in Slack api to send a message everytime the user starts a new conversation with a bot?

Tags: python, bots, slack, slack-api

I'm developing a slackbot using python. It's already up and running. But I would like it to send a greeting message everytime someone starts a new conversation with it. Is there any way in slack python api to detect conversation's start?

Haven't tried anything yet.

I want my bot to send a greeting message everytime a new user starts a new conversation with it. Original Slackbot built in slack does this.

Comment: what do you mean by "starts a conversation"? exactly? Do you want your bot to reply to a mention in an channel or direct messages or both? When exactly do you want your bot to reply?

Comment: Starts a NEW conversation. Important word but I missed it, sorry. I mean situation like this: you get info from your mate that he developed a bot, you search it in users, you click to start a conversation and bum. He sends you greetings. So something like automatic default message being displayed at the beginning of your DM with bot

Comment: Cannot provide any photo becouse I'm new on Stack Overflow. But if you scroll to the very beginning of your conversation with Slackbot you will see some text like: "feel free to ask me simple questions" etc. I mean something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the event type [`app_home_opened`](https://api.slack.com/events/app_home_opened) is what you are looking for.

> This app event notifies your app when a user has entered into the App
>   Home space—that's the place where a user exchanges DMs with your app.

(...)

> Use the `app_home_opened` event to begin a friendly onboarding flow from
>   your app, a whimsical welcome message, or a deep-dive into a detailed
>   dialog. Since the app_home_opened event is only sent to your app when
>   a user has already clicked on your app, you can rest assured that your
>   attentions are welcome.